# PhpStorm does not use a profile that knows the Java home path

Tags: java, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, file-watcher

I have configured a File Watcher in PhpStorm at `./node_modules/.bin/yuicompressor`. Whenever this executes, I get a prompt on my Macbook to install Java. Java is installed and the paths have been set so that when I execute `java` in the PhpStorm terminal, iTerm, or the preinstalled Terminal application Java is found and can be executed. However, when the File Watcher attempts to execute it still prompts for Java to be installed.

I assume this means that PhpStorm is not using the correct profile? ZSH is configured as the default terminal for my PhpStorm instance and Java executes from the ZSH command line everywhere I test it.

Answer (score 0):

While restarting other applications did the trick. The host had to be restarted in order for PHPStorm to accept the changes.